# vue component html does not show up

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am having difficulty in getting the component html shown in browser 
I have a component called fullName which contains

```
<template>
 <div>
   <h3>
    {{data.firstName}} {{data.lastName}}
   </h3>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
 name: 'fullName',
 props:{
  data:Object
 }
}
</script>
```

and i pass firstName and lastName as props but when I inspect in chrome the component shows up like this

```
 <fullName data=[object object]></fullName>
```

instead of

```
 <div>
   <h3>Abhishek Singh</h3>
 </div>
```

where I pass Abhishek and Singh as props

can someone help me to debug this or let me know why it is happening

Comment: It seems you didn't register `fullName` component inside the parent component - for more information: [Component Registration](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html)

Comment: @Muhammadvakili I register the component if i have not registered it there should be a console error

Comment: Have you fixed the problem? If not can you share how this component is used so we can have a better look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you register the fullName component in its parent component properly?

Comment: I register the component if i have not registered it there should be a console error